# Manifest merger error: Package name 'uninitialized.application.id' used in: AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, gradle, android-manifest

After a gradle update in a multi module project I get the following error when building:

```
Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs
```

The error logs in the Merged Manifest show the following warnings:
[image: Merged Manifest logs]

I tried the suggested solutions for SO posts about 'manifest merger failed with multiple errors' but they yielded no results so for now I'm assuming that the warnings are the actual problem and there seem to be no posts about this issue yet.
None of the manifest files in my project have an incorrect or non-existent package name but the merged manifest does indeed show "unitialized.application.id" as package name. Does anyone happen to know how to fix this and/or where this package name/application id comes from?

Comment: Did you found a solution to this? I am having the exact same problem.

Comment: The build problem seemed unrelated to the manifest merging warnings but related to the targetSDK. I had upped the target SDK to 31 but 31 fails to work and changing it back to 30 fixed the issue. My compile SDK is still 31.

Comment: this is just a warning, you probably forgot to add android:exported on some components with intent filters, are there errors listed below this?

Comment: any updates? I'm having the same issue - updated target SDK to API 31

Answer (score 2):

The issue seemed to be related to target SDK 31. Changing it back to 30 fixes it. The compile SDK can stay at 31.

Comment: downgrading isn't a solution